# How to take the latest entry from a data.frame and store it in new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that is full of data, and where the data for parameters repeat itself, but I want to use the latest information that is stored.

Thankfully I have an index in the files that tells me which duplicate is he current row in the data.frame.

Example for my problem is the following:

```
    A    B    C    D
1   1    2    3    1
2   1    2    2    2
3   3    4    2    2
4   3    4    1    3
5   2    3    2    1
6   2    1    1    1
```

A small explanation ... A and B columns can be considered key, and the C column represents value for that key ... the column D represents the index of the measurement .. but it does not have to start from 1 ... it can start from 3,6, ... any integer. This is happening because the data is incomplete

So at the end the output should be like:

```
    A    B    C    D
2   1    2    2    2
4   3    4    1    3
5   2    3    2    1
6   2    1    1    1
```

Can you please help me program a make an R program, or point me to the right direction, that is going to save all the keys with the their latest index ...

I have tried using for loops but it didn't work ....

Sincerely thanks

If you have any question feel free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `duplicated` and subsetting in base R, you can do

```
dat[!duplicated(dat[,1:2], fromLast=TRUE),]
  A B C D
2 1 2 2 2
4 3 4 1 3
5 2 3 2 1
6 2 1 1 1
```

`duplicated` returns a logical vector indicating whether a row (here the first two columns) has been duplicated. The `fromLast` argument initiates this process from the bottom of the data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` verbs to group your data `group_by`, then sort `arrange`. The `do` verb allows you to operate at the group-level. `tail` grabs the last row of each group...

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
          group_by(A,B) %>%
          arrange(D) %>%
          do(tail(.,1)) %>%
          ungroup()
```

Thanks to `Frank's` suggestion, you could also use `slice`

```
df1 <- df %>%
          group_by(A,B) %>%
          arrange(D) %>%
          slice(n()) %>%
          ungroup()
```

Comment: Maybe `slice(n())` or something instead of `do`.